# A book series about a young boy and his alien companion Glr

Tags: story-identification, books

I am trying to find a series of books involving a young boy and what I think was a search for his father, who is a member of some sort of space-faring order. The boy has a companion called Glr... and that's all I can recall. This has haunted me for forty years, so I am hopeful.

Comment: In the [Last Legionary series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Last_Legionary) _Glr_ is an avian alien who is the companion of _Keill_. But this seems a long way from your description.

Comment: The Last Legionary series has been asked about [many times already](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bstory-identification%5D+glr)!

Comment: is that what it was called? Had I recalled this, Mr Rennie, I would not have asked... but thank you for providing this, however left-handed.

Comment: Hi Mike :-) Are you saying this is the book? I didn't think it could be because Keill doesn't team up with Grl until he is an adult, and there is no search for his father. I mentioned it only because it seemed such a coincidence to have such an unusual name in two books.

Comment: My first thought was also The Last Legionary, by Canadian author Douglas Hill: As well as Glr, Keill Randor also spends a lot of time searching for the other Legions (the space-faring order), and there are flashbacks to when he was younger, as well as the 'Young Legionary' prequel.

Comment: Although I don't think it's the work you're looking for, your description is vague enough that you could answer it with  _[Empire Star](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empire_Star)_...the boy's goal is vague, he has a feline companion named _Di'k_, and an artificial consciousness companion called the _Lump_, based on the consciousness of a member of a race called _Lll_.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like the Aliens Ate My Homework series, which has a character named BKR. There is a search for the main character’s missing father, who turns out to be a spacefaring alien.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Does this involve a search for the boy's father?  Is BKR the boy's companion?  Please describe how this matches the question.

Comment: There is a search for the main character’s missing father, who turns out to be a spacefaring alien. BKR is an alien at the boy’s school who eventually becomes the villain (though I haven’t read the entire series, so that could change).

Comment: That’s some useful information that should be [edit]ed into the question